# Remove duplicates without using list mutation

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to remove adjacent duplicates from a list without using list mutations like del or remove. Below is the code I tried:

```
def remove_dups(L):   
    L = [x for x in range(0,len(L)) if L[x] != L[x-1]]
    

    return L

print(remove_dups([1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,1,1,1]))
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 3, 6, 7, 8]
```

Can anyone explain me how this output occurred? I want to understand the flow but I wasn't able to do it even with debugging in VS code.

Input:

```
[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,1,1,1]
```

Expected output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,1]
```

Comment: You are producing the *indexes* of non-duplicated values, rather than the values themselves.  Something like `[L[x] for x in ...` might work.

Comment: It should be noted that comparing element at position 0 with element at position -1 will have the effect of comparing the first and last elements of the list, which could have nasty side effects: example: [1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1] will output [2,1] while [2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1] will output [2,1,2,1]. (after using L(x) as suggested.

Comment: Yea my code doesn't work because I won't get the first element in output

Comment: If the first and last elements are different,you will get the first element. The solution is to add `x > 0 and` right after if.

Comment: How about using `itertools.groupby`? I am not in front of a computer right now, but `[k for k, _ in itertools.groupby(L)]` would work I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll replace the variables to make this more readable

```
def remove_dups(L):   
    L = [x for x in range(0,len(L)) if L[x] != L[x-1]]
```

becomes:

```
def remove_dups(lst):   
   return [index for index in range(len(lst)) if lst[index] != lst[index-1]]
```

You can see, instead of looping over the items of the list it is instead looping over the indices of the array comparing the value at one index `lst[index]` to the value at the previous index `lst[index-1]` and only migrating/copying the value if they don't match

The two main issues are:

1. the first index it is compared to is `-1` which is the last item of the list (compared to the first)
2. this is actually returning the indices of the non-duplicated items.

To make this work, I'd use the enumerate function which returns the item and it's index as follows:

```
def remove_dups(lst):   
   return [item for index, item in enumerate(lst[:-1]) if item != lst[index+1]] + [lst[-1]]
```

Here what I'm doing is looping through all of the items except for the last one `[:-1]` and checking if the item matches the next item, only adding it if it doesn't

Finally, because the last value isn't read we append it to the output  `+ [lst[-1]]`.

Comment: Read the first comment. He is getting the indices instead of the values.

Comment: @Tarik I noted the same thing...

Comment: Reflect it in the proposed code.

Comment: @Tarik look at his expected output, he may be getting the indices, but he wants the values. I don't think its wise to propose code that also gives him the incorrect answer just because his current code does...

Comment: under "expected output" I see values not indices.

Comment: @Tarik My proposed code outputs values....

Comment: His question was why doesn't his code work, the first part of my answer answers that. The second part of my answer proposes code that does work -- it returns values

Comment: No worries -- it's late here haha. I was really confused though. Cheers

Comment: At my place it's 06:20AM :-) Saudi Arabia

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def remove_dups(L):
    return [k for k,g in groupby(L)]

L2 = remove_dups([1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,1,1,1])
```

Output: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]`

Comment: So we meet again @mozway lol, another great answer